# JQuery Ajax Post results in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to perform this AJAX post but for some reason I am getting a server 500 error. I can see it hit break points in the controller. So the problem seems to be on the callback. Anyone?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "InlineNotes/Note.ashx?id=" + noteid,
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[1]);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

This is the string that should be returned:

```
{status:'200', text: 'Something'}
```

Comment: .ashx = .NET platform? What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: is it possible to make the call correctly without $ sign or jQuery prefix in front of ".ajax"?

Comment: Yes.. I am using the jQuery.noConflicts(). The prefix is correct. Like I said. It makes the request.. but the error is returned.

Comment: Check the post here http://www.developersnote.com/2014/01/solved-jquery-ajax-500-internal-server.html

Comment: The link above from @shamcs contains a string at the end that renders it invalid. The correct link is http://www.developersnote.com/2014/01/solved-jquery-ajax-500-internal-server.html

Comment: I had the same issue - in my case I had to disable the error_reporting in my php script, therefore my form was submitted 2 times -> throwing a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I suspect that the server method is throwing an exception after it passes your breakpoint.  Use Firefox/Firebug or the IE8 developer tools to look at the actual response you are getting from the server.  If there has been an exception you'll get the YSOD html, which should help you figure out where to look.

One more thing -- your data property should be {} not "{}", the former is an empty object while the latter is a string that is invalid as a query parameter.  Better yet, just leave it out if you aren't passing any data.

Comment: Your first sentence is misleading (implying the 500 error is occuring client-side). I nearly downvoted you for it before I read the answer more thoroughly. You might want to clarify a bit.

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/ is also very useful to view the actual response from the server.

Comment: :o something Chrome Dev Tools actually falls short on!

Comment: actually you can debug this in Chrome, check out this answer for details http://stackoverflow.com/a/21786593/14533

Answer (score 35):

in case if someone using the codeigniter framework, the problem may be caused by the csrf protection config enabled.

Comment: I just went into this problem some minutes ago... your answer gave me the hint :) Maybe interesting for others to avoid this
Adding this to the data solves the problem: 
<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?> : '<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>'

Comment: Thank you, got stuck on this in Bonfire and don't know CodeIgniter well enough yet to figure that out.

Answer (score 20):

This is Ajax Request Simple Code To Fetch Data Through Ajax Request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "InlineNotes/Note.ashx",
    data: '{"id":"' + noteid+'"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  i removed this line then my problem solved

Comment: what if you use that line anyway? @Taja_100

Answer (score 19):

I just had this problem myself, even though i couldn't find the reason for it in my case, when  changing from `POST` to `GET`, the problem 500 error disappeared!

```
 type:'POST'
```

Comment: but not a real solution. Some things has to be POST

Comment: That's completely wrong. If changing POST to GET actually worked then you were using the incorrect HTTPVerb in first place. If you must use POST because for example you're sending a payload, you must used POST and using GET would not work. And on the other hand if you're just getting something and can use GET, do not use POST, GET gets cached (depending sometimes on configuration)

Answer (score 17):

I experienced a similar compound  error, which required two solutions.  In my case the technology stack was  MVC/ ASP.NET / IIS/ JQuery.   The server side was failing with a 500 error, and this was occurring before the request was handled by the controller making the debug on the server side difficult.

The following client side debug enabled me to determine the server error

In the  $.ajax error call back, display the error detail to the console

```
  error: (error) => {
                     console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   }
```

This at least, enabled me to view the initial server error

*“The JSON request was too large  to be serialized”*

This was resolved in the client web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
```

However, the request **still** failed. But this time with a different error that I was now able to debug on the server side

*“Request Entity too large”*

This was resolved by adding the following  to the service  web.config

```
<configuration>
…
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"  />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

The configuration values may require further tuning, but at least it resolved the server errors caused by the ajax post.

Comment: I just got confused whether it need to be add on server web.config or client's web.config?
Also Will you please explain how this code is working that will really help. I am printing the logs as you mentioned over here and it is saying the lingth of the string exceeds the value set of the maxJson length property.

Answer (score 10):

You can look up HTTP status codes [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) (or [here](https://http.cat)), this error is telling you:

"The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request."

You need to debug your server.

Comment: Thanks, I had this problem, in the action file I couldn't connect to database to store data so jQuery post().done() got an 500 error.

Answer (score 9):

I run into the same thing today. As suggested before get Firebug for Firefox, Enable Console and preview POST response. That helped me to find out how stupid the problem was. My action was expecting value of a type int and I was posting string.  (ASP.NET MVC2)

Answer (score 7):

There should be an event logged in the EventVwr (Warning from asp.net), which could provide you more details on where the error could be.

Answer (score 5):

A 500 from ASP.NET probably means an unhandled exception was thrown at some point when serving the request.

I suggest you attach a debugger to the web server process (assuming you have access).

One strange thing: You make a POST request to the server, but you do not pass any data (everything is in the query string). Perhaps it should be a GET request instead?

You should also double check that the URL is correct.

Comment: Right.. I was using a GET originally but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried doing the request from the browsers address bar? Do you get a 500 status then as well?

Answer (score 5):

I just face this problem today. with this kind of error, you won't get any responses from server, therefore, it's very hard to locate the problem.

But I can tell you "500 internal server error" is error with server not client, you got an error in server side script. Comment out the code closure by closure and try to run it again, you'll soon find out you miss a character somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get that error in VB if the function you're calling starts with **Public Shared Function** rather than **Public Function** in the webservice. (As might happen if you move or copy the function out of a class). Just another thing to watch for.

Answer (score 3):

Can you post the signature of your method that is supposed to accept this post?

Additionally I get the same error message, possibly for a different reason. My YSOD talked about the dictionary not containing a value for the non-nullable value. 
The way I got the YSOD information was to put a breakpoint in the $.ajax function that handled an error return as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function SubmitAjax(url, message, successFunc, errorFunc) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:message,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:successFunc,
        error:errorFunc
        });

};
```

Then my errorFunc javascript is like this:

```
function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#install").text("Error doing auto-installer search, proceed with ticket submission\n"
        +request.statusText); }
```

Using IE I went to view menu -> script debugger -> break at next statement.
Then went to trigger the code that would launch my post. This usually took me somewhere deep inside jQuery's library instead of where I wanted, because the select drop down opening triggered jQuery. So I hit StepOver, then the actual next line also would break, which was where I wanted to be. Then VS goes into client side(dynamic) mode for that page, and I put in a break on the `$("#install")` line so I could see (using mouse over debugging) what was in request, textStatus, errorThrown. request. In request.ResponseText there was an html message where I saw:

```
<title>The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'appId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult CheckForInstaller(Int32)' in 'HLIT_TicketingMVC.Controllers.TicketController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.<br>Parameter name: parameters</title>
```

so check all that, and post your controller method signature in case that's part of the issue

Answer (score 2):

I found myself having this error to. I had .htaccess redirect configured in a directory. Well it reroutes ajax calls to ofcourse (`$.post(../ajax.php)`), so it couldn't find the actual file (resulting in 500 error).

I 'fixed' it by placing the ajax.php in a directory (So `.htaccess` didn't affect).

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was simple issue, but hard to find. Page directive had wrong Inherits attributes. It just need to include the top level and it worked.

**Wrong code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="BusLogic.aspx.cs" Inherits="BusLogic"%>
```

**Correct code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="BusLogic.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.BusLogic" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the solution using the **Chrome** debugger (I don't have Firebug or other third-party tools installed)

- Go to developer tab (CTRL+MAJ+I)
- **Network** > click on the request which failed, in red > **Preview**

It showed me that I had a problem on the server, when I was returning a value which was self-referencing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this occurred in chrome when I did two ajax queries in the jquery '**on load**' handler,

i.e. like `$(function() { $.ajax() ... $.ajax() ... });`

I avoided it using:

```
setTimeout(function_to_do_2nd_ajax_request, 1);
```

it's presumably a chrome and/or jquery bug

Answer (score 1):

When using the CodeIgniter framework with CSRF protection enabled, load the following script in every page where an ajax POST may happen:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {
            <?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_token_name'); ?>: $.cookie('<?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_cookie_name'); ?>')
        }
    });
});
```

Requires: jQuery and jQuery.cookie plugin

Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7154317/2539869 and http://jerel.co/blog/2012/03/a-simple-solution-to-codeigniter-csrf-protection-and-ajax

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because the page I called ajax post from had `EnableViewState="false"` and `EnableViewStateMac="false"` but not the page called.

When I put this on both pages everything started to work. I suspected this when I saw MAC address exception.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data you are passing to the server should have same name as you forming in client side.
Ex:

```
var obj = {  Id: $('#CompanyId').val(),
             Name: $("#CompanyName").val()
            };

$.Ajax(data: obj,
url: "home/InsertCompany".....
```

If the name is different, ex:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertCompany(Int32 Id, string WrongName)
{
}
```

You will get this error.

If you are not passing the data, remove the data attribute from AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and found out that the server side C# method should be **static**.

Client Side:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/ListItem_Selected",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: ListItemElectionSuccess,
            error: ListItemElectionError
        });

        function ListItemElectionSuccess(data) {
            alert([data.d]);
        }
        function ListItemElectionError(data) {

        }
```

Server Side:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static String ListItem_Selected()
    {
        return "server responce";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get an example on How To Get the JSON Object and properties on the server side? If data: {Prop1:"asdf", Prop2:"zxcv"} then How Do I get Prop1 and Prop2 values inside public static String ListItem_Selected() function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned I think your return string data is very long. so the JSON format has been corrupted.

There's other way for this problem. You should change the max size for JSON data in this way :

Open the Web.Config file and paste these lines into the configuration section

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Try Catch block on your server side and in the catch block pass back the exception error to the client.  This should give you a helpful error message.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. Here are two ways by which I have solved it-
1. If you're using some framework, make sure you are sending a CSRF token with the ajax call as well
Here is how the syntax will look like for laravel -

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In your js file make sure to call this before sending the ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X_CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
```

2. Another way to solve it would be to change `method` from `post` to `get`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the error was in php file to which i was sending request.
Error was in database connectivity. After fixing the php code, error resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains dataType: **json**.

In this case jQuery evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The **JSON** data is parsed in a strict manner. Any malformed **JSON** is rejected and a parse error is thrown. An empty response is also rejected.

The server should return a response of `null` or `{}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with AJAX code that sporadically returns the "500 internal server error". I resolved the problem by increasing the "fastCGI" RequestTimeout and ActivityTimeout values.

Comment: Which web server does that concern? Could you add some code please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late on this, but I was having this issue and what I've learned was that it was an error on my PHP code (in my case the syntax of a select to the db). Usually this error 500 is something to do using syntax - in my experience. In other word: "peopleware" issue! :D

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the "malformed JSON" answer, if the query you are running returns an object or anything that prevents the data to be serialised, you will get this error. You should always be sure you have JSON and only JSON at the end of your action method or whatever it is you are getting the data from.

Answer (score 0):

Usually your property is not completely right or something wrong with your server processing.

Answer (score 0):

try this
headers: {
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
},
in ajax,
set type above the url

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was related to the way entity framework works. I had a one to many relationship between two tables in my database and when I was bringing data from the table which has the foreign key using ajax post it was also fetching the related foreign key table data because lazyloading was enabled by default. because of that , Json return got confused about the data format and was throwing this error.
So I had to use
`_wfocEntities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` this line before my linq query and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was trying server side processing for datatables. And my action method returns thousands of user record as JSON. The problem was **JSON max length**. This solved my problem.

```
return new JsonResult()
        {
            ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default,
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Data = returnData,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue //this is what,I needed.
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

Your return string data can be very long.

```
<system.web>        
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
```

**For example:**

- 1 Char = 1 Byte
- 5 Char = 5 Byte
- "Hakki" = 5 Byte