# Using AJAX in Sitecore rendering with XSLT

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sitecore, asp.net-ajax, sitecore6

I am new to Sitecore and .NET. I got an old existing project which is based on Sitecore 6.5 and rendered content by XSLT with .NET Framework 3.5.

Now what I need to create a page that can make an AJAX call so that the page need not to be refreshed and new content can be generated. I am quite familiar with AJAX call with PHP, yet I am quite confused on those in .NET.

I googled and found most of the tutorial are based on Razor view rendering.

Can anyone provide me a full picture that how can I do to meet my objective?

I wonder if the following steps are correct:

1. Create a .xslt for rendering different content based on matching the URL parameter that passed into
2. Create a .ashx to get the .xslt content
3. JavaScript AJAX call to the .ashx and convert the xml content to HTML

Any examples that I can follow?

Thanks!

============================================

Update:
I tried the above flow and can print Hello World by AJAX successfully.
However, I am not sure how to get the content from XSLT in the following .ashx file with different parameter?

And are there any HttpPost/IsPostBack that can help to check if the .ashx is visited by a POST method?

[image]

Comment: You can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349118/jquery-ajax-post-results-in-500-internal-server-error) question that can help you.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I updated my question above. I can call AJAX successfully but face difficult when handling the communication between XSLT and .ashx!

Comment: I don't think I can specifically answer your question, but it may be worth looking at the documentation for the HttpContext object to help you understand how to work with a generic handler: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the question with the following steps.

1. Create a .ashx to render the sitecore content.
   I have compared with .ashx, .aspx and .asmx. Seems .ashx is the best choice.

   ```
   using Sitecore.Configuration;
   using Sitecore.Data;
   using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
   using Sitecore.Data.Items;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;

   namespace MYPROJECT.Web
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Summary description for AjaxTest
       /// </summary>
       public class AjaxTest : IHttpHandler
       {
           public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
           {
               context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
               string ID = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];
               Database master = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
               Item source = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home/MYPROJECT/gallery");
               Item[] items = source.GetChildren().ToArray();
               context.Response.Write(items[ID].Fields["image"].Value); 
           }

           public bool IsReusable
           {
               get
               {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

p.s I removed some validation codes from above.

2. JavaScript AJAX call to the .ashx.

   ```
       $j('#ajax_test').click(function(){
           $j.ajax({
               //type: 'POST',
               url: '/AjaxTest.ashx?ID='+$j('#inputunmber').val(),  
               //dataType: 'html',
               //data: form.find(':input').serialize(),
               success: function( response ) {
                   $j('.test_result').append(response);
               },
               error: function (xhr) {
                   alert("Error:" + xhr.responseText);
               }
           });  
       });
   ```