# Tinymce editor in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working in core PHP with the Tinymce editor code.

The Tinymce is working correctly on my localhost. When I upload to a live server it is not working.

The Tinymce editor layout is not displayed on the add new and edit page.

This is my site: http://tinymce.studioscue.in/

Comment: You did not added jQuery in your code. there are errors like  `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):12
(anonymous) @ (index):12
(index):100Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):100
(anonymous) @ (index):100
favicon.ico:1 GET http://tinymce.studioscue.in/favicon.ico 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Include jQuery. for any error use debugger to debug

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of jQuery [CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) you can add it as follows.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there is 500 - Internal Server Error ?? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349118/jquery-ajax-post-results-in-500-internal-server-error) for that error.

Comment: hey,
                                                                                                                    i used your shared script in the edit page
but still it's not working.

please you check once & reply me asap.

the site link is: ' http://tinymce.studioscue.in/'
the edit page link is :  ' http://tinymce.studioscue.in/edit_mce.php?mce_id=MQ==%20%22&%3C%C2%A0%20%C3%83%CE%A7!%CF%92%CF%85%20%22&%3E%E2%82%AC%20%C2%A0%C3%81%C3%82%22&%20%C2%B4%C3%86%C2%A9%22&&%20%22%C3%89%CF%96%CE%A0%201%22&%CF%91%CE%98%20%22&'

and you can check there is no error now.

thank you
Neha

Comment: Use firebug or do cltr+u and check your source code. Still jQuery is not added there ?

Comment: in your edit page link, there are 500 Internal server error occurs ? jQuery is there but other files not loading there ? for example see [this link of skin.min.css](http://tinymce.studioscue.in/plugin/tinymce/skins/Lightgray/skin.min.css)

Comment: hey,

i checked on the edit page's source code with ctrl+u & your shared file is added there

here is the link of edit page :
http://tinymce.studioscue.in/edit_mce.php?mce_id=MQ==%20%22&%3C%C2%A0%20%C3%83%CE%A7!%CF%92%CF%85%20%22&%3E%E2%82%AC%20%C2%A0%C3%81%C3%82%22&%20%C2%B4%C3%86%C2%A9%22&&%20%22%C3%89%CF%96%CE%A0%201%22&%CF%91%CE%98%20%22&

& the error issue was different thing & i sort that part you can check now.& i have add your shared script in the bottom of the page 

please check again there & reply me asap
thank you 
Neha

Comment: Don't you have a firebug, or use chrome and do `F12` you can see the errors like this `http://tinymce.studioscue.in/plugin/tinymce/skins/Lightgray/skin.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: yes i see this error when i open your shared this link: http://tinymce.studioscue.in/plugin/tinymce/skins/Lightgray/skin.min.css

& this bcz of i am not using this css file in my code

should i use this css file 
tell me then i will add this file 'skin.min.css' in the edit page too.

thanks
Neha

Comment: hey,
thanks for your help i have add that skin.min.css file in my code & now its working on my live server.

thank you so much 
Have a great day
Neha

Comment: Welcome :) Please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: @neha: it looks like this answer contributed to your success. Please accept it by clicking the 'tick' mark in the usual way, to thank this volunteer for their time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code missed jQuery file, just try adding this, and try again with your code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey, i used your shared script in the edit page