# 500 (Internal Server Error) with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I encounter this block of error message yet I can't figure out where gone wrong with the code.

```
POST http://localhost/get_state.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4ajax @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
getState @ index.php:14onchange @ index.php:34
ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:542
```

The database contains two tables which called Country & States.  When country is selected, it will show states which belongs to that country.

Below are the codes.

File name: **index.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "test_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else{
$country=array();
$sql ="SELECT * FROM country";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>jQuery Dependent DropDown List - Countries and States</TITLE>
<head>
<style>
body{width:610px;}
.frmDronpDown {border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;background-color:#C8EEFD;margin: 2px 0px;padding:40px;}
.demoInputBox {padding: 10px;border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;background-color: #FFF;width: 50%;}
.row{padding-bottom:15px;}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_state.php",
    data:'country_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#state-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}

function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="frmDronpDown">
<div class="row">
<label>Country:</label><br/>
<select name="country" id="country-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getState(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<?php
    while($country=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>State:</label><br/>
<select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
<option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**File name: get_state.php**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "test_db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

if(!empty($_POST["country_id"])) {
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID = '" . $_POST["country_id"] . "'";
    $results = $conn->query($sql);
?>
    <option value="">Select State</option>
<?php
    while($state=$result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $state["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Ajax Post results in 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349118/jquery-ajax-post-results-in-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: See the error log file of your Apache, you will find details there

Comment: You have a typo: You set the variable `$results`, but then you use `$result->fetch_assoc()`.