# how to send ajax POST request

Tags: ajax

I am using this method to send post request but it gives me error 500 internal error for jquery.1.11.1.min.js.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("cashondelivery", "Home")',
                data: "",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (data) {

                    alert(data);

                }
            });

         });

    //this is action method in controller
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult cashondelivery(productinfoModel mmodel)
    {
      return View();
    }
```

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349118/jquery-ajax-post-results-in-500-internal-server-error

Comment: it works well on localhost but getting error after uploading it on godaddy

Comment: I think file permission issue. please give permission this file in which you want to call ajax.

Comment: what type of permission i have to give to file

Comment: for file you need to give 644 permission to access

Comment: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 68.178.252.229:25 this is the actual error ,I am sending email  in action method and there i am getting this error because of it ajax getting an error

Comment: solve my problem with same code,there was problem in sending parameter

Answer (score 0):

try to call the url in DHC(chrome plugin),the response status code 500 means server internal error, it's the server-webapp developer's mistake. not your mistake.